# Reading several input files in Python

Tags: python, excel

I have several Excel files that I would like to read in with my code. Instead of using the following command with the explicit file name:

```
df = read_excel("a.xlsx",sheet_name=0)
```

I would like to list all of my Excel file names in a .txt file (like data.txt) and then read data.txt line by line to store each Excel file name in a variable: i.e. after reading the first line of data.txt which is a.xlsx, I will assign

```
var1 = a.xlsx
```

My question is how do I open a.xlsx afterwards.

```
df = read_excel(var1,sheet_name=0)
```

does not work. 
Is there a way to open Excel files without having their names explicitly written out in Python?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using `pandas`?

Comment: `var1 = a.xlsx` is not valid python unless `a.xlsx` exists. That's probably not what you want. You want `var1 = 'a.xlsx'`.

Comment: What do you mean by `does not work`? What error do you get?

Comment: Yes, I am using pandas.

Comment: The error is: No such file or directory: '"a.xlsx"\r\n'

Comment: I tried changing the entries in data.txt as "a.xlsx" to include the quotations (instead of a.xlsx w/o quotations)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do `var1.rstrip()` to remove `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you text file is like this **new.txt**  remove the quotes ("") from the text file. you completely misunderstood the comments.

```
a.xlsx
b.xlsx
c.xlsx
```

your code should be something like this:

```
file = open("new.txt")
for var in file:
    df = read_excel(var.strip(),sheet_name=0) // reading the files one by one
    // Do some processing
```

This just a skelton.
You are getting that error is because there are some extra characters when reading
the file (\r\n). The strip function would remove those characters and any white spaces.

Comment: and it still says IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Comment: However wen I write a.xlsx directly in read_excel command (and I am not using var1) it works and does not complain with no such file or directory.